# Deactivating web Feature causes error, "DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, branding

I have a feature receiver that changes the homepage of a site (rootfolder.welcomepage).  The feature deploys fine but on deactivation it shows an unhandled exception error.  The feature receiver seems to be successful, though, and it changes the homepage back.  I have debugged the feature receiver and the error is not occurring until after it completes the receiver logic and tries to go back to the _layouts/managesettings.aspx page.  Basically, debugging doesn't show any error.